# Mapping keyboard shortcuts to sequences of keys

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, macros

On Mac OS, I'm extensively using the emacs-like bindings (C-a to go to the beginning of line, C-k to delete the whole line, etc.) I'd like to emulate this behaviour on Windows, so I'd like to press ctrl-a to home, ctrl-k to run a script that deleted the rest of the line (or perhaps a macro: shift down, end, shift up, delete). Is it possible to achieve this behavior or emulate it somehow in Windows?

Answer (score 2):

You can try Autohotkey ( http://www.autohotkey.com/ ). You can pretty much do whatever you want with it, and if you stick to keyboard shortcuts it is not too difficult.

Comment: Agree with Anne, AHK is great